# A Simple explanation for Process vs Threads

Tags: multithreading, process

Can anybody distinguish between between process and a thread. I have read a lot on the web but most of them are confusing enough.

Comment: Please add what confuses you? I'm sure I can explain confusing too.

Answer (score 4):

Forgive my analogy but think of a process as the body and thread as the mind or soul.

Process is the abstraction that represents resources related to your application such as memory (virtual, physical, etc...), security and other kernel related properties.

Threads are where actual execution happens. It is the life of a process. Matter of fact, when the operating system is asked to run a process, it starts by allocating all the process required resource, but the process is not getting into action or life yet till the OS creates and starts the execution of the process first and main thread.

After the process last thread stop execution, the process start the actual death, (and cleanup).

I intentionally tried to make things less dry. I hope I succeeded :).

Comment: Brilliant Explanation. Thumbs Up

Comment: +1 - sounds OK to me!

Answer (score 1):

A process is something that is executed by a processor (CPU), and has its own resources, e.g. an own address space. Therefore it is isolated from other processed by the operating system, as far as possible.
In contrast, a thread is a "light weighted" process that shares its resources, particularly its address space, with other threads. These threads can easily communicate with each other using the common address space. But since they are not isolated from each other, they can influence each other in possibly tricky ways.
ADDED:
"light weight" means that it requires much less "administrative" work from the operating system than a process. A process switch, e.g., requires to switch the address space using the memory management unit, which takes considerable time. To switch from one thread to another one in the same addressing space is thus MUCH faster. For the same reason, a process communication requires more work from the OS than a communication between threads in the same addressing space. So, light weight simply means threads require less work from the operating system.

Comment: You've mentioned -thread is a "light weighted" process. How so? can you explain me on this? I'm a bit puzzled

Comment: @geeko_zac: I just added an explanation to my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my own selection of clarifying statements :-)

- A *process* is a program (e.g. a file ending in .exe) that the OS runs. The OS keeps processes apart so that a process runs in parallel with, independent from and unaffected by the behaviour of all other processes (*unless it chooses otherwise*). OSes are not quite perfect so that isn't always true, but that's the idea.
- A process contains at least one *thread* of execution, i.e. a sequence of instructions that are executed one after another.
- A process can contain more than one thread if the initial thread starts more of them. Each thread runs its sequence of instructions in parallel with the other threads (or at least that's what the OS endeavours to achieve).
- It is normally the case that threads in a process interact by accessing *shared resources* (memory, network connections, etc.)
- You use objects such as *semaphores* and *mutexes* to ensure that when a thread accesses a *shared resource* it has exclusive use of that resource. Other threads contending for the resource are halted by the OS until it becomes available again, at which point they're resumed. This is called a *context switch*.
- A process can access *named* shared resources and use *named* semaphores / mutexes to interact with another process in a similar way. The difference is that the OS has to context switch a whole process instead of a whole thread. On most OSes this is takes a lot longer, and so is generally avoided for reasons of efficiency.